# concurrent user read and update to mysql using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, singleton, record-locking

I have a problem on my program, by solving this issue, it maybe can be done by using singleton method.  But, i read from some article, they said,it is not a good way to implement it as the asp.net application concurrent users might have a lot.

My problem is,system running number is base on the particular record in the database example:

- document_type="INV" , document_year=2015 , document_month=04, document_running=0102.
- document_type="INV" , document_year=2015 , document_month=05, document_running=0002.

Therefore, when user create a new record, the logic of getting the new running number as below:

1. Get the document type = "inv" , current year and current month,
2. If not found. create a new  document type , year and month record with the running number 0001.
3. if found. running + 1.

now, the problem come out. my situation is 5 users received the record information 
as when they pressed "save" button to create a new record:
- document_type="INV" , document_year=2015 , document_month=05, document_running=0002.

and 5 users get the same running number INV15-05-0003 ( after 0002 + 1).
By right, should be INV15-05-0003, INV15-05-0004, INV15-05-0005, INV15-05-0006 and INV15-05-0007.

how we should do to avoid if all users getting the wrong/outdated information.
hope you all able to understand on my poor english.
Regards,
MH

Comment: can you show some existing code and or logic that you are using.. is this logic done on both the database as well as in C# code..? sounds like you are doing something incorrectly within the save logic but I doubt anyone can accurately answer this since you have not provided any code..

Comment: @MethodMan actually there no any complicated code, it just a simple logic but it have problem when come to multiple user access concurrently. logic is each user receive the row information and do the incremental logic in asp.net, then when update back to the database , other concurrent user may already have the old information and do the same incremental logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see is to use a lock on the method you are calling to do the database management.

```
public class Dal
{
    private static object syncObject = new object();

    public static void InsertUpdate(...) 
    {
        lock (syncObject)
        {
            // 1. Get the document type = "inv" , current year and current month,
            // 2. If not found. create a new document type , year and month record with the running number 0001.
            // 3. if found. running + 1.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your replied. is it something like singleton? I felt this is what I want. any how , will do a test.

Comment: No singleton here, but just a common way to avoid concurrency :-)

Comment: ok thanks,  I have data access layer for this database,  but, i read it store in memory and after modified base on my logic, and then call this data access layer again to update back.    This another transaction will it wait until this lock is released or it will by pass?

Comment: The first who invoke the method acquire the lock and any other invoker will wait until the lock is released and then served.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way you can get close to desired effect is to use Auto Incrementing for document_running field: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html.

Warning: Be aware, in this case your document_running is always going to be unique across all documents, not just for the records with the same type/year/month.

Alternative solution:
Use GUID as document_running field. The same warning applies.